# Limit maximum height of <div> despite text being longer

Tags: overflow, netsuite, bfo

I'm creating a document using the BFO Report library (embedded in NetSuite ERP).
I have a text block which I would like to limit to two lines, truncating if it's more than that, but I can't seem to get `overflow:hidden` to actually do anything. Setting `height` limits the *minimum* height, but if the text is longer it extends the containing  rather than being cut off.

Here's the document I'm rendering:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC '-//big.faceless.org//report' 'report-1.1.dtd'>
<pdf>
    <body width="3in" height="1.25in" padding="0">
        <div font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14pt" width="3in" height="2em" border="1px solid green" overflow="hidden">
            <p margin="0">Short Name</p>
        </div>
        <pbr/>
        <div font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14pt" width="3in" height="2em" border="1px solid green" overflow="hidden">
            <p margin="0">This Is An Item With A Really Extremely Long Name That Doesn't Fit</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</pdf>
```

And the resulting PDF:

[image: "Short Name" is in a box approximately twice as high as the text, but "Really Extremely Long Name" has pushed the containing box out further than it's supposed to.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BFO `overflow` attribute tag only works on absolutely positioned elements, as per [their documentation](https://bfo.com/products/report/docs/tags/atts/overflow.html):

> If a block is absolutely positioned and larger than it's parent element, what to do with the content that "overflows" the parent elements block.

It appears the element containing the content you want to control must be positioned absolutely, but the `overflow` attribute can be applied to the parent element.  So you can add `position="absolute"` to your `<p>` element for the effect you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC '-//big.faceless.org//report' 'report-1.1.dtd'>
<pdf>
    <body width="3in" height="1.25in" padding="0">
        <div font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14pt" width="3in" height="2em" 
border="1px solid green" overflow="hidden">
            <p margin="0">Short Name</p>
        </div>
        <pbr/>
        <div font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14pt" width="3in" height="2em" border="1px solid green" overflow="hidden">
            <p position="absolute" margin="0">This Is An Item With A Really Extremely Long Name That Doesn't Fit</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</pdf>
```

[image]

Comment: I read that documentation and somehow overlooked that sentence. Thanks for the help!